# running shell scripts in c++

Tags: c++

Ive been writing the folowing code:

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <stdlib.h> 
using namespace std; 
  int main() {  
  cout << "The script will be executed"; 
  system("./simple.sh");  
}
```

But when I run it the shell script is executed first.
What can I do to execute "cout << "The script will be executed"" first?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Flushing the output stream buffer should be enough. You can do this with

```
cout << "The script will be executed";
cout.flush();
```

Alternatively, if you intended to also print a newline character then you can use `std::endl` which implicitly flushes the buffer:

```
cout << "The script will be executed" << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not flushing the output stream.

Try:

```
cout << "The script will be executed" << endl; // or cout.flush()
system("./simple.sh");
```

The script is executed second, the delay between the call to `cout` and printing to the console is probably throwing you off.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `cerr << "The script will be executed";`
when you're trying to print something using `cout` it keeps that in buffer. `cerr` is printing immediately but @Jon answered better.

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing out the stdout stream before calling the system() syscall.